# "Cannot allocate memory" Exception in Python (multiprocessing), but free memory is available

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I have the problem that some python-code will throw "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory".

But it seems i have plenty of free memory  :(

Its a complex python code which i am not able to post as whole, but here is the snipped where process.start() is called. And i already put some output of the memory-stats right infront of the start():

```
from multiprocessing import Process
self.log.info("mem-info: {}".format(psutil.virtual_memory()))
self.log.info("swap-info: {}".format(psutil.swap_memory()))
self.process.start()
```

And self.process is a Process():

```
self.process = Process(name="lth" + laneid, target=self.run, args=())
```

The memory-output looks like this:

```
mem-info: svmem(total=8375971840, available=5189591040, percent=38.0, used=2836029440, free=2907832320, active=4075716608, inactive=569372672, buffers=591847424, cached=2040262656, shared=37097472, slab=743190528)
swap-info: sswap(total=4291817472, used=0, free=4291817472, percent=0.0, sin=0, sout=0)
```

Stacktrace:

```
File "LaneThread.py", line 49, in start
    self.process.start()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

So i have a lot of free memory, but still got the "Cannot allocate memory". Is there any other reason possible which cause this "Cannot allocate memory" Exception?

I don't have an idea what i can look for to fix the problem  :(

Code is executed by a jenkins-node running Debian10 an python 2.7 (upgrade is planned for this year, but not possible right now).